# How to plant a Yoshino Cherry Tree successfully?

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-health, soil, plant-recommendations, tree-care

I purchased four Yoshino Cherry Tree saplings. I want to know the best way to ensure their growth success in my region.

I am located in midwestern Indiana *(hardiness Zone 5a)*. I've read that I need to place them in an area with plenty of direct, unobstructed sunlight. It is also recommended to have them in a well drained, relatively acidic portion of my property.

Aside from watering regular over the course of the first year, what other best practices should I perform to ensure the trees are well taken care of during the early stages of soil prep, planting, wintering, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Be nice to see a picture of the trees and their new environment.  Are these trees bare root or balled and burlapped?  If bare root, light staking will be necessary.  If balled and burlapped with little canopy do not stake.  Do not plant too deeply.  Only the top of the rootball should be under the soil.  The entire trunk has to be kept free of soil, mulch, rock...so make sure when you dig that hole you do not dig deeper than the depth of the rootball otherwise the rootball and tree will sink and if that trunk is covered by soil anything that will hold moisture against the bark, you'll eventually lose your tree.

Dig your hole, do NOT mess with any soil amendments!  This tree has to thrive in the native soil.  Are you planting on level ground or on a slope?  Tree wells and/or perforated PVC pipe will vastly help with getting water to the roots.  Fertilizer is just not necessary this year unless...welp, just send more information.  Mychorrhizae is a cool thing to add for any plant being transplanted!

Send pictures of the tree's branching, perhaps we can help do the initial pruning for health as nurseries tend to promote crazy branching.  And water WELL.

Oh, and place the root ball in your hole, then rotate to best view, stand it up straight and get that burlap off.  Any wire baskets are fine to leave in place but that burlap and ALL TIES ALL LABELS need to be cut off.

Try not to stake, your tree will grow and mature faster and provide its own support far more quickly.  Did you ever break a bone and get a cast?  Remember what happened to your limb after the cast was removed?  Trees NEED MOVEMENT to grow bigger, stronger root systems, more stout trunks.  Staking in my experience is just not necessary in most cases.  Trust me...?  Grins.

Comment: As soon as I receive the trees I will post back some photos. Thank you for your insights already helping me!

Comment: Cool...send pictures of where you are thinking of planting these guys.  Also the correct name of species, variety.  Are they bare root?  More than likely, huh if coming by mail?